# HTML Name and Surname Validation Pattern Problem Turkish character

Tags: html

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <div class="form-item m-b-20">
        <input type="hidden" name="konu" value="Estetik">
        <input type="hidden" name="digerbilgi1" value="Türkçe">
        <input type="hidden" name="referans" value="Landing Page (Yeni)">
        <input type="hidden" name="talep" value="Estetik Hakkında Bilgi Almak İstiyorum">
        <input class="input" type="text" name="ad" id="ad" pattern="^(\w\w+)\s(\w+)$" placeholder="Ad Soyad" maxlength="30" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <div class="form-item m-b-20">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="telefon-ulke-kodsuz" id="phone" placeholder="Telefon" minlength="7" maxlength="15" required="required">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="div-gizle-mobil button button-primary transition-3d-hover pull-left">Gönder</button>
      <button type="submit" class="div-gizle button4 button-primary transition-3d-hover pull-left m-b-10">Gönder</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Hi, I'm getting the first and last name section from users in one line, and some users don't type their last name. I tried to do a verification to prevent this, but it gives an error when entering a turkish character, for example: ğ, İ, etc. Know the reason I wonder is there?

```
**<input class="input" type="text" name="ad" id="ad" pattern="^(\w\w+)\s(\w+)$" placeholder="Ad Soyad" maxlength="30" required>**
```

Comment: I don't have a solution for this, but I advise against trying to validate names like this, you will always miss something and make someone feel excluded because their name "is not a real name". It should be enough to make the field `required`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `^([\p{L}\p{N}]{2,})\s+([\p{L}\p{N}]+)$`

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <div class="form-item m-b-20">
            <input type="hidden" name="konu" value="Estetik">
            <input type="hidden" name="digerbilgi1" value="Türkçe">
            <input type="hidden" name="referans" value="Landing Page (Yeni)">
            <input type="hidden" name="talep" value="Estetik Hakkında Bilgi Almak İstiyorum">
            <input class="input" type="text" name="ad" id="ad" pattern="^([\p{L}\p{N}]{2,})\s+([\p{L}\p{N}]+)$" placeholder="Ad Soyad" maxlength="30" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <div class="form-item m-b-20">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="telefon-ulke-kodsuz" id="phone" placeholder="Telefon" minlength="7" maxlength="15" required="required">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="div-gizle-mobil button button-primary transition-3d-hover pull-left">Gönder</button>
        <button type="submit" class="div-gizle button4 button-primary transition-3d-hover pull-left m-b-10">Gönder</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

`\w` Only matches characters `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9`, and `_`

Since Turkish characters are outside of a-z, instead of `\w` you need to use the `\p{L}` token which will match a letter of any language, and `\p{N}` token, which will match a number of any language

```
^                 // Start of line
(                 // Start of capture group
    [             // Start of character class
        \p{L}     // Any letter character of any language
        \p{N}     // Any number character of any language
    ]             // End of character class
    {2,}          // Two or more
)                 // End of capture group
\s                // White space
+                 // One or more
(                 // Start of capture
    [             // Start of character class
        \p{L}     // Any letter character of any language
        \p{N}     // Any number character of any language
    ]             // End of character class
    +             // One or more
)                 // End of capture group
$                 // End of line
```

[Test Here](https://regex101.com/r/PeGeu8/1)